# Efficient webapp developing

Tags: django, workflow

Is not efficient :).

I'm trying to learn django by building a simple app. I bought a hosting plan on webfaction, set up github account and a putty on my Windows machine. I'm writing the "code" on my Windows, pushing it to github repo, then connecting via putty to my webfaction account to pull from github.

This is extremely tedious and boring process and I can't help but wonder that I'm doing something wrong. Even fixing a simple typo takes a lot of time. Are developers writing everything server-side using vim? This sound even less encouraging. Can I do something to improve my workflow? How it's done by professionals?

Comment: Test on your local machine. Problem solved.

Comment: The Web App Developers deployment process is typically Save, Refresh Browser.  Ensure you are deploying on your local server... only push to your test/qa/prod server(s) when you're done locally.

Comment: Out of curiosity, by what means are you learning django? What tutorial or book are you working from? I ask because it seems your source has not explained the "getting started" aspect of learning django. You don't need to worry about this whole deployment phase yet. It doesn't even need to be part of your current learning step. Also, I would remove that very first sentence of your question because it makes you look very naive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop wasting your own time, which you are if you are editing code on the server. There are many reasons why you shouldn't deploy code that way the most important ones is that you'll waste time and also importantly is that you'll break things while users are looking at the site.

Setup a development server locally, this is why the django `manage.py runserver` [exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/). If you for some reason can't run it on windows, then install a server in virtualbox, mount the folder in windows where your code is and run it off that (this is what we do for our designers although we have a lot of dependencies).

There are IDE's out there that enables you to run Django via a GUI that you might find more comfortable, I use [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) and I hear good things about [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse).

You'd save time if you learned how [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.2/index.html) worked so you can automate your deploy process. I am unsure how well fabric works on windows, but I'm sure you can use [cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin) or similar to get it working.

A fairly basic example would be this one:

```
from fabric.api import *

env.hosts = ['ubuntu@example.org']

def deploy():
    pid_file = "~/myproject/process.pid"
    with cd('~/myproject/'):
        run('git pull')
        run('src/city_nomads/manage.py collectstatic --noinput')
        # If the process isn't up we don't want the thing to exit.
        with settings(warn_only=True):
            run("cat {} | xargs kill -TERM".format(pid_file))
        run("src/myproject/manage.py runfcgi "
                "method=threaded "
                "host=127.0.0.1 "
                "port=8000 "
                "pidfile={} "
                "--settings=myproject.settings_release".format(pid_file))
```

It'll SSH into my server, pull the source, collectstatic, kill the process if it's there and then run django as fastcgi. I'm assuming you have [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) or [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) set up to connect to Django on port 8000.

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I think the entire deploy explanation is irrelevant to the OPs actual problem. The real answer is just the first part that tells the OP how to start the dev server.

Comment: @jdi I'm trying to make his processes more efficient and he mentioned that part too and fabric speeds up that particular part pretty well. I did however simplify my fabfile quite a bit to not be too confusing. :)

Answer (score 2):

To summarise Kit Sunde's answer: you shouldn't be deploying to the server until you've actually got a site to deploy. Normal development and testing is done locally, using `manage.py runserver` and a local db. This works fine on Windows.

Comment: +1 as this was all that was required to answer the OPs question. Much easier :-)